# Can I run garbage collector after installing plutus-apps?

Tags: plutus

I just finished installing plutus-apps and running nix-shell for the first time on a new computer. I noticed that the file size is pushing 60gb is there anyway for me to clean up some of the unused files. I read that nix garbage collector or `nix-store --gc` will cut down on some of this but I'm afraid I might lose some of the plutus-apps files and have to rebuild again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually delete any nix store with `nix store delete`, just remember if there is a symbolic link pointing to a nix store, nix will refuse to delete it, you shoud remove any dependency first.